# Trying to identify a story about breaking out of a predefined path and no one notices

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember reading a short story many years ago where something happens and the protagonist gets a bit "out of step" with the rest of the world.  Everyone else keeps acting as if he's still doing what he would have been doing before the event, to the point of carrying on one-sided conversations and the like.  I can't remember much of the plot, but the premise stuck with me.

**Edit:** To try and explain it more clearly, based on the comment I just wrote, I *think* everyone else was effectively acting like they were robots with a prerecorded program.  If someone would normally wake up, drink coffee, put on pants, then walk out the door to catch a bus, then if the protagonist broke his coffee cup, stole his pants, and jammed the door, the victim would pour coffee into a broken/nonexistent cup, walk out pantsless, but when he got to the jammed door he might suddenly realize something was up (and thus being "out of step" spreads) or he might continue to go through the motions.  In either case, no one else would notice that the victim was pantsless (or that he didn't make it to work)...

How much of this actually came up in the story, I don't remember.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how he was behaving strangely?  What is the time setting and the place?

Comment: @Robin - one example has to do with a manually-operated elevator.  He gets in a few minutes early (I don't remember how he knew that), and the operator doesn't react at all.  I think he ends up taking the stairs.  Then a few minutes later, after he reached the floor he wanted, the elevator reaches that floor and the operator is having a conversation with someone who isn't there (him).  I *think* that was his concrete clue something was going on.  What I recall of the setting seemed mid-20th century.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short story/novella wherein everyone's following patterns like parts of a machine](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51642/short-story-novella-wherein-everyones-following-patterns-like-parts-of-a-machin)

Comment: @Richard - Generally the newer question is marked as a duplicate of an older question.  I'm not sure what the etiquette is with identification questions, though - just because the answer is the same doesn't mean the questions are.

Comment: @Bobson - General rule of thumb is that the newer ident question is marked as a dupe. If you wanna get fancy, you can ask a moderator to roll the answers over.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like Fritz Leiber's *The Sinful Ones* (An abridged version was published as the title story of a collection, *You're All Alone*.).

One [review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671655493) says:

> Carr McKay is a clerk at General Employment. One day, a frightened young woman comes in, asking if he's one of "them," and if he's been "awakened." Carr has no idea what she is talking about. A few minutes later, a man sits at Carr's desk, pretending to smoke a cigarette, and answering employment-type questions like he's talking to an invisible person. One of Carr's colleagues suddenly starts ignoring him. His original thought is that this is some kind of strange joke, He soon learns differently.

A cover image might refresh your memory:

- *The Sinful Ones*: [1980](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?230925), [1986](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47332)
- *You're All Alone*: [1972](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55782), [1990](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0881846791), [2010](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?364603)

Comment: That sounds *very* much like it.  I'll see if I can track down a copy.  I probably read the abridged version.

Comment: I read the start of it off of Google Books, and you got it right.  "Merely by coming a few minutes ahead of time, merely by omitting to shave, he had broken the clock-work rhythm.  That was why the clerk hadn't spoken to him, that was why the elevator hadn't worked when he'd first pushed the button, ... It wasn't *time* yet for those little acts in the clockworks show."  Thanks for helping me finally track it down!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is the Choose Your Own Adventure book [Cave of Time](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/190917.The_Cave_of_Time) In one of the end scenarios the character (you) end up stuck out of time by 5 minutes.

It always struck me as strange because it didn't actually seem feasible in that like your example he is moving 5 minutes ahead of the rest of the world and yet everyone reacts to him mostly the same. He gets on a bus and no one notices him yet five minutes later the bus wouldn't be there so he would just walk out into traffic yet that doesn't happen. If this isn't what you were thinking of then I would like to read your book or story to see if it makes sense.

Comment: Definitely wasn't a CYOA.  In this case it would be more of either A) The bus stops, he gets on and no one acknowledges him (the driver may even close the door on him), no one makes room for him, and he can push the stop button but the driver won't stop (because it's not what should be happening), or B) He's not there, but the bus stops anyway, people make room for an empty space to squeeze on, someone apologizes for stepping on a non-existent foot, and then the driver stops to let no one off, even though the bell wasn't pushed.

Answer (score 2):

No elevators in it, but Terry Pratchett's *Mort* has the theme you're asking about.  In this novel, the queen is alive but almost everyone else pretends she's dead.  The protagonist Mort tries to convince everyone that the queen is alive, without much success.

Answer (score 0):

Was it [Neverwhere, by Neil Gaiman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwhere_%28novel%29)?

Comment: The bit about "He appears to have become invisible; he loses his job, where no one seems to recognize him, and his apartment is rented out to other people." sounds similar, but the rest is not at all familiar, and even that is more about "I disappeared" than "I'm not in the right place".  Also, I'm pretty sure it was in a short story collection, not a whole novel, although I could be wrong.  Thanks, though - I have something new to go read now! :)